# Dúvidas sobre a função realloc

Tags: c

realloc realoca "negativamente" a memória? Quer dizer, se o tamanho original de um vetor for maior do que o valor passado na realocação, o vetor será reduzido?

Por exemplo, se eu faço isso:

```
char *exemplo = calloc(256, sizeof(char)); 
strcpy(exemplo, "Teste"); 
exemplo = realloc(exemplo, 3 * sizeof(char)); 
printf("%s\n", exemplo);
```

Por que continua imprimindo "Teste"? É como se o espaço alocado ainda permanecesse...

Comment: Nota: por definição `sizeof (char)` é `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em C o espaço que você reserva para os dasdos e como você efetivametne usa esses dados são duas coisas separadas.

COmo o sizeof(char)  é sempre 1, você de fato, ao chamar o realloc deixou apenas 3 bytes reservados para o seu texto de exemplo - como você esperava.

Só que a função "printf" não sabe disso - ao buscar uma string para impressão, como o código de controle "%s" ela vai imprimir toda a string de destino até encontrar um caractére `\x00`. Se não houver nenhum antes do final da área alocada para a astrign pdem acotnecer uma de duas coisas: o seu programa termina com um segmentatin fault, ou, o pritnf consome dados de uma área de uma área em que podem estar sendo usados para outras coisas dentro do seu programa. Por concidencia, os bytes que você liberou com o realloc continuaram dentro de um segmento usado no seu programa *e* esses dados não foram usados por mais nada - então seu `printf` funcionou.

Mas a grande lição para se ter em memte é: em C não existe nenhum mecanismo automático que vai "parar" o acesso a memória e restringi-lo a areas que você alocou (seja com malloc, seja reservando as dimensões na declaração de variável) - você é responsável por saber que todas as funções chamadas pelo seu programa estão acessando areas de memória permitidas.

Se quiser verfificação automática de tamanhos de vetores, e etc, só vai encontrar isso em linguagens de mais algo nível - Java, Go, Pythn, RUby, etc... Em C, e C++ é você e a CPU.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vocês são demais!

Answer (score 3):

Ao reduzires o espaço reservado para `exemplo` para 3 bytes, o conteúdo desses 3 bytes é `'T'`, `'e'`, `'s'` (nota especialmente a ausência de `'\0'`), ou seja, esse conteúdo deixou de der uma *string*.
Ao passares essa *não string* para `printf()` qualquer coisa pode acontecer: é **Comportamento Não Definido**.

Um exemplo desse comportamento é o programa fazer o que tu esperas ... excepto às sextas-feira de lua nova.

Experimenta

```
exemplo = realloc(exemplo, 3);
exemplo[2] = 0; // fazer uma string
printf("%s\n", exemplo);
```

ou

```
exemplo = realloc(exemplo, 3);
printf("%.3s\n", exemplo); // imprimir 3 caracteres excepto se houver um '\0' antes
```